# How to pass and read an array of strings as a url parameter and how to read the query parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a url http:example.com/index.html?hideuielements=["Bookmark","Favourite"]

I want to know if this is possible and valid query parameter which we can pass to a url and if yes how will we be able read it in the javascript ?

I am expecting something like `query.hideuielements` to give me something like 
`["Bookmark", "Favorite"]` in the js file.

Any leads would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

To pass the array you can simply concat the array with the URL. For example for you reference I am contacting it with the location.href in the code.

```
location.href += '?view_id=home;mode=embed;hideUIElements=[%22Bookmark%22,%22Filter%22,%22Favourite%22];'
```

To get the array you can use the following code if you have only one query (hideuielements) as the query else you have to create an array of queries by splitting the location.search with & operator. If you have only one query then my code will work properly.

```
    var query={};
location.href.split("?")[1].split(";").forEach(each=>{
    if(each.split("=")[0] === "hideUIElements") {
        query[each.split("=")[0]]=JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(each.split("=")[1]));
    }
})

    console.log(query)
```

Can you please check once and let me know if this is what you are looking for or not?

Comment: What if I have my location.href looks like view_id=home;mode=embed;hideUIElements=[%22Bookmark%22,%22Filter%22,%22Favourite%22];
and order could be varying and we want to pick up only ```hideuielemnts``` as an array query

Comment: That means there can be multiple queries right?
like this: view_id=home&mode=embed&hideUIElements=[%22Bookmark%22,%22Filter%22,%22Favourite%22]

Comment: Yes but they are getting passed as string you need to figure out a way to convert them into a data structure like array or object

Comment: Can you please give me the URL? Actually multiple queries are separated by & operator but in your comment, I am seeing it is separated by ; . So I am a little bit confused which one should I take.

Comment: I have upvoted your question. Okay give me some time I am giving you the solution.

Comment: I have updated the above code. Can you please check once? @Amit

Comment: Happy to hear that :) Can you mark the answer as correct if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to read data from a url you should use url parameters then catch them with a server-side language like `php` for example:

```
www.my_site.com?hide=true&ui1=Bookmarks&ui2=Favourite
```

Then the php to fetch the results from the url:

```
<?php
$hide = $_GET["hide"];
$ui_array = array($_GET["ui1"], $_GET["ui2"]);
#$ui_array will contain the values "Bookmarks" and "Favourite"

#Then the Javascript
echo "<script>
if(" . $hide . " == true){
    //Do something with $ui_array
    something.hideuielements(" . $ui_array . ");
}
</script>";
?>
```